# Does a single-element set have a limit point?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

According to definition of limit point:

> Point $x_0$ is called limit point of a set X ⊆ R, if *any* deleted neighbourhood has at least one point from X, i.e. $\forall e>0 \space \exists x_e \in X \cap O_e(x_0)$

, where $O_e(x_0)=(x_0-e,x_0+e)/\{x_0\}$ (i.e. **without $x_0$**),

does not set $X = \{5\}$ have limit point?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are singletons limit points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3995245/are-singletons-limit-points)

Comment: @AnuragA, probably yes, but this is question about numerical sets, from the basic analysis, so such terms as topological space are not familiar for me. I think, I need first learn analysis, before topology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

$5$ can't be a limit point because there are no other elements of $X$.   Nothing else can be a limit point because if $x \neq 5$ then let $e < |x-5|$ and the deleted neighborhood will not intersect $X$

Comment: So the singletons aren't closed on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Singletons are closed.   The set of limit points isn't the same as the closure.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense, thanks!